# Is there a way to trigger JIT manually other than java.lang.Compiler

Tags: java, compiler-optimization, jvm-hotspot

I'm trying to build a JIT strategy based on method structure with profiling info (provided by JVM) but i didn't able to trigger JIT manually. [This documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Compiler.html) says i can run JIT by invoking `java.lang.Compiler.compileClass()` but method returns false every time and the property that `java.lang.Compiler` checks (java.compiler) is null every time i run the JVM. I tried on OpenJDK and Oracle JVM 1.7 both results the same.

However when i observe the compilation statistics with

```
$ jstat -printcompilation <PID>
```

I can see the JIT successfully compiles some method which fits the conditions.

If any way exist I rather trigger it from java code. I tried to search in [hotspot VM's code](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7u) too but I couldn't locate the class and method where the decision made and JIT start.

**Edit: After looking around more I found the [compilationPolicy.cpp](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7u/jdk7u/hotspot/file/a89267b51c40/src/share/vm/runtime/compilationPolicy.cpp) bu still couldn't find the exact location that the decision depend on. I would expect something like (simply thinking)**

```
if(hot_count > Threshold){
   compile_method(methodHandle);
}
```

but instead found this,

```
void SimpleCompPolicy::method_invocation_event(methodHandle m, JavaThread* thread) {
const int comp_level = CompLevel_highest_tier;
  const int hot_count = m->invocation_count();
  reset_counter_for_invocation_event(m);
  const char* comment = "count";

  if (is_compilation_enabled() && can_be_compiled(m)) {
    nmethod* nm = m->code();
    if (nm == NULL ) {
    // [MY COMMENT] no check being done on hot_count in here or callee methods
      CompileBroker::compile_method(m, InvocationEntryBci, comp_level, m, hot_count, comment, thread);
    }
  }
}
```

As far as tracing the native JVM code, im getting away my main topic. **Still looking for a simple solution to use in java side of the code**.

Comment: Are you sure that you have the `java.compiler` property enabled on your machine?  The documentation you referenced makes an explicit reference of that needing to be set.  You can check with `System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.compiler"));`.

Comment: `System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.compiler"));` code prints null.And i am not sure i should set a value by myself even if should i cant find any documentation to set a specific value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you want something similar to the Compiler Control feature (http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/165).

Unfortunately, it doesn't exist yet, although it is currently scheduled to form part of Java 9.

Comment: Yes, i want something like that, to be more specific programmatic control. But i dont understand `java.lang.Compiler` class existence in the current JDK. If this class is a feature for different vendors to control JDK, why hotspot does not provide a default implementation  to use 'Compiler'.